# Codecoverage.exe does not generate output xml

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage

In order to import a coverage file to SonarQube, I'm executing CodeCoverage.exe to convert a ".coverage" file to xml.
I execute a cmd line like: `CodeCoverage.exe analyze /output:[name of xml file to be generated] [name of the coverage binary file].coverage` but I do not get any output xml and no errors.
I must say that I was able to generate such xml for tests of other solution files.
What can be the problem? How can I troubleshoot it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would start with making sure you're naming the new file with the extension *.coveragexml

`CodeCoverage.exe analyze /output:[name of xml file to be generated].coveragexml [name of the coverage binary file].coverage`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I feel it does, at the very least, give him help in figuring out his problem if his specific problem is he is not specifying the correct file extension in his output it would actually fix the problem.
If he were using just *.xml in his statement instead of *.coveragexml and he changed that as I'm asking him to ensure, then it would, in fact, be the answer to this question.

Comment: Making the output file extension .coveragexml worked for me, whereas a .xml extension did not create the output file

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue.  There should be errors in the event log.  What fixed it for me was using an absolute path to the .coverage file.  .xml extension for the output file is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a same problem today and I finally found a workaround: use tools created by one of *stackoverflow.com* users: @stef-heyenrath:

[CoverageConverter - GitHub](https://github.com/StefH/CoverageConverter)

In short:

1. Install CoverageConverter tool by command:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-coverageconverter`

2. Convert `.coverage` file to `.coveragexml`:

`dotnet-coverageconverter --CoverageFilesFolder "ProjectName.Tests\TestResults\DirectoryContainsCoverageFile"`

3. Done :)

Generated file it's fully supported by SonarQube btw.